# Android Studio emulator rotates weird

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I've just begun (today) learning how to code for Android. I have my first basic app up and running, but when I rotate the emulator, it goes into this really weird view. I don't know how to explain it, so I'll just attach a screenshot:

[image: Weird Emulator Behavior]

As you can see, half of the screen is rotated one direction, and half of the screen is rotated another direction. Only one side of the screen can be interacted with -- the other side is "dead" and doesn't respond to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug with Android Studio 4.1 + Big Sur:

https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues

The suggested fixes both work (copying here for posterity):

- Go to the Apple Menu, select System Preferences > General. In the
  Prefer tabs when opening documents option, select "never". Then
  restart Android Studio.
- Upgrade to Android Studio 4.2, currently available in the Beta channel.